# Help using usb c to power display

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, protocol, usb-c, hdmi

[image]

Here is a bad diagram of a project I’m working on. In a beginner to EE and this stuff. I have a laptop display connected to a controller board I got on eBay. It has a input of hdmi and a dc power jack 12v 2A. I want to convert it to usb c so I can power and transmit date from my laptop. Building a custom board is to hard for me. I’m thinking I can get a breakout board and wire the Vbus and GND and I think the CC1 or CC2 lines to another breakout board on the same pins, then plug the breakout board to a pre made power negotiator zy12pdn and power the controll board from that. For the video transmission I connect the data lines from breakout board to another breakout board on the same pins then use a usb c to hdmi adaptor to the board. The reason I’m using so many breakout boards is I can’t solder the wires to the usb c head.  Would this work? Assuming my laptop will give me the 24W will the protocol and the alt mode for usb work? If you can please provide and information about usb c and maybe after some research I could just make my own custom usb c receiver. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that your setup is going to work. I see several issues:

- The USB-C-to-HDMI adapter most likely expects a power supply of 5V on VDD. If your YZ12PDN board negotiates 12V, it will likely kill the adapter.
- Video data is transferred using USB-C Alternate Mode. In order to activate it, it needs to be negotiated via CC1/CC2. This is in conflict with YZ12PDN use of CC1/CC2.
- I'm not aware of any computer or laptop that can provide 12V. The USB-C specification certainly allows it. But I've only seen it implemented in power supplies.
- Video data is transferred using high-speed data rate requiring properly shielded cables with controlled impedance. Flying wires between break-out boards will not work. They will pick up noise, distort the signal and make it unusable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve been going crazy thinking of a solution.  I’ll just have to go with a dc jack and hdmi for the board. Where can I go to learn more about the usb c protocols and perhaps later in the future develop my own negotiation board or something like that?

Comment: I'm not aware of any comprehensive, easy to read documentation. With its variety of operating modes, interoperability and backward compatibility, USB C is very complex. Most articles about USB C cover just one aspect and usually in an incremental fashion (*what's new in version xx*). Read through several articles you'll find on the internet and finally dive into the official specifications: *Universal Serial Bus Type-C Cable and Connector Specification* (373 pages) and *Universal Serial Bus Power Delivery Specification* (659 pages).